# SSLv3 connection with ssl librairie in Python

Tags: python-2.7, ssl, openssl, sslv3

I want to make a programm (Python 2.7) which detect the ssl/tls version which are available on a website. And I just want to use standard Python librairies.

Here is my code:

```
#encoding=utf-8

import ssl
import socket
import traceback
import logging
import sys
import json

class AnalyseSSL:

cipher_list="RC4-SHA".split(":")    



list_version_ssl_tls = [
    ("SSLv2", ssl.OP_ALL | ssl.OP_NO_SSLv3 | ssl.OP_NO_TLSv1 | ssl.OP_NO_TLSv1_1 | ssl.OP_NO_TLSv1_2),
    ("SSLv3", ssl.OP_ALL | ssl.OP_NO_SSLv2 | ssl.OP_NO_TLSv1 | ssl.OP_NO_TLSv1_1 | ssl.OP_NO_TLSv1_2),
    ("TLSv1", ssl.OP_ALL | ssl.OP_NO_SSLv2 | ssl.OP_NO_SSLv3 | ssl.OP_NO_TLSv1_1 | ssl.OP_NO_TLSv1_2),
    ("TLSv1_1", ssl.OP_ALL | ssl.OP_NO_SSLv2 | ssl.OP_NO_SSLv3 | ssl.OP_NO_TLSv1 | ssl.OP_NO_TLSv1_2),
    ("TLSv1_2", ssl.OP_ALL | ssl.OP_NO_SSLv2 | ssl.OP_NO_SSLv3 | ssl.OP_NO_TLSv1 | ssl.OP_NO_TLSv1_1),
]





def __init__(self, hostname, port):
    self.hostname = hostname
    self.port = port


# try to connect to the hostname with all cipher suite for each SSL/TLS version
def try_all_ssl_tls_version(self):
    logging.warning("---------------------------------------- %s", port)
    nb_tentative_max = 5
    cpt_tentative_max = 0
    resultat = {}

    try:
        print 'hostname : ', hostname
        for version in self.list_version_ssl_tls:                                           # Pour chaque version de SSL/TLS
            cpt_nb_tentative_max = 0
            is_version_supported = False
            if cpt_tentative_max >= 5:
                    break;
            for cipher_suite in self.cipher_list:                                                # Pour chaque cipher suite
                print cipher_suite
        context = ssl.create_default_context(ssl.Purpose.SERVER_AUTH)                   # création du context
                context.check_hostname = False
                context.verify_mode = ssl.CERT_NONE
                context.options = version[1]                                                   # on spécifie la version de SSL/TLS qu'on veut utiliser
        print context.options

        try:
                    context.set_ciphers(cipher_suite)                                       # on spécifie la cipher suite à utiliser
                except Exception as e:
                    print "Exception : ", e
        pass                        
        traceback.print_exc(e)


                s_ = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_STREAM)
                s = context.wrap_socket(s_)
                #s = context.wrap_socket(s_, server_hostname=hostname)
                #print "timeout : ", s.gettimeout()
                s.settimeout(5)
                #print "timeout : ", s.gettimeout()


                try:
                    s.connect((hostname, port))                                                 # on tente de se connecter
                    if (is_version_supported == False):
                        print version[0], "supporté"
                        is_version_supported = True
                    print s.cipher()
                    #logging.info("---------------------------------------- %s %s", %(version[0], s.cipher()))
                    s.close()

                except socket.timeout:
                    cpt_tentative_max += 1
                    if cpt_tentative_max >= 5:
                        break;
                except Exception as e:                                                                         # si la connexion a échoué
                    #print "[version ", version[0], " with ", cipher_suite, " :: ", e
                    #print s.getpeercert()
                    #traceback.print_exc(e)
        print e
                    pass
            if is_version_supported == False:
                print version[0], "non supporté"

            print "\n"
    except Exception as e:
        print e
    traceback.print_exec(e)
    pass

hostname = 'PUT YOUR IP HERE'
port = 443

A = AnalyseSSL(hostname, port)
A.try_all_ssl_tls_version()
```

The problem is i cant etablish an sslv3 connection.
I've got an ip (and i'm sure sslv3 is enable on this ip with cipher suite suite RC4-SHA, i tested it with openssl and testssl.sh).

My program work fine for the third tls version but it's impossible to use sslv3 or sslv2. Here is the error i've got :

```
[SSL: UNSUPPORTED_PROTOCOL] unsupported protocol (_ssl.c:581)
```

I cant use SSLv3, but why ? (I recompile my openssl librairie in order to enable sslv3 and it works because if i use :

```
 openssl s_client -connect IP -ssl3 -ciphers RC4-SHA
```

that's works.

How can I solve this ? 
Thx :)

Answer (score 0):

```
openssl s_client -ssl3 -tls1.2
```

try to add to tls1.2 , i had The Same Probleme With My Linux When I Used TLS 1.2 It Worked Fine

And In Other Linux , It Didnt Work , so , I Desactivated the SSL Certificate Check

Comment: I have no problem with openssl (the openssl command work fine). My problem is when i use my script with ssl libraries, it doesn't works (and check certificate is disable in my script).

Comment: can you give where The Terminal Give you the error , in what line

Comment: AN exception is raised and it said SSL3 is an unsppoted protocol.

Answer (score 0):

AN exception is raised and it said SSL3 is an unsppoted protocol.

```
RC4-SHA
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "test.py", line 72, in try_all_ssl_tls_version
    s.connect((hostname, port))                                                      # on tente de se connecter
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/ssl.py", line 882, in connect
    self._real_connect(addr, False)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/ssl.py", line 873, in _real_connect
    self.do_handshake()
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/ssl.py", line 846, in do_handshake
    self._sslobj.do_handshake()
SSLError: [SSL: UNSUPPORTED_PROTOCOL] unsupported protocol (_ssl.c:726)
[SSL: UNSUPPORTED_PROTOCOL] unsupported protocol (_ssl.c:726)
SSLv3 non supporté
```

Answer (score 0):

Try to set proper [context.minimum_version](https://docs.python.org/3/library/ssl.html#ssl.SSLContext.minimum_version) on each request to avoid unsupported protocol error and/or random connection closes from server-side.